# When i execute "setState" i get this error on emulator screen "Bad State: Stream has been already listened to."

Tags: android, flutter, dart, setstate

I think it's about `Easy Localization` cause the error line send me to `return EasyLocalization (...)`
I researched and people solve their problem with initializing the key, but i tried it too and it hasn't worked.

Code Snippet:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //The error raises here <-------------
    return EasyLocalization(
      // key: context.widget.key,
      path: 'resources/langs',
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      child: MaterialApp(...)
```

Comment: if you are using a `StreamController` close that controller in `dispose()` method of the widget

Comment: i don't have `StreamController` this is why it's so confusing

Answer (score 0):

i think you have a `StreamController`, any given `streamController` can be listened to by one entity at a time, but in your case multiple entity is trying to listen to it, which is causing the problem, do this in the streamController `StreamControoller<your_type>.broadcast()` will fix the problem.

Comment: i don't have `StreamController` in this page

Comment: EasyLocalization has one inside it i guess

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found the solution. I initialized `EasyLocalization` twice in one page that's why i get this error. I removed the `EasyLocalization` widget that wraps `MaterialApp` widget and problem solved.